# Executing a text file as Python source code

Tags: python

How can I run a text file use Python?

For example; if the text file is called `textfile.txt`, and it contains the line:

```
print("Hello")
```

How can I use Python to run this as lines of code?

Comment: `python textfile.txt` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use exec: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec
so your code would look somehow like this:

```
filehandle = open("filename.txt","r")
code_to_execute = filehandle.read()
exec(code_to_execute)
```

remeber that your file has to have correct syntax so no syntax error occours (mostly its about indentation)

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the python interpreter and pass it the file as such:

```
python yourfile.txt
```